10Base-T Half Duplex Segment Length 100m?
Considering 10Base-T Half Duplex...
Is the maximum segment length of 100m a timing constraint (from CSMA/CD)?
Is it derived from the slot time / minimum packet size?
Or is it an electrical performance constraint (attenuation etc.) of the cable used?
Conversely, is there a stated minimum cable length (or minimum segment length) between end device and switch required, so as to ensure Collision Detection works during Half Duplex operation?
Regards.

10Base-T can run on Category-3 (analog voice) cabling. Category-5 cabling has been deprecated for a quarter of a century. The currently registered cable categories are 3, 5e, 6, 6A and 8. All the other categories have been deprecated.

edited to remove the term cat 5 in the question

The 100m constraint is a very old constraint. At the time, it was a design decision for 10BASE-T.
IEEE could have used a larger distance (say 500m like 10BASE5 or 185m like 10BASE2), but then all the equipment that would implement 10BASE-T (cables, repeaters, NICs, bridges, etc) would have to be more sensitive and capable (translating to being more expensive). A basic tenet of the IEEE 802.3 Working Groups was that Ethernet had to be cheap. Cheap meant smaller distances. And to further lower costs, the cable type and characteristics that the 10BASE-T working group had to select had to be easy and streamlined to installa (lower training for installers, lower breakage during installations, more durable cabling).
After a compromise was made between usefulness (a 100m physical link is quite useful) and expected price per NIC/cable, the standard was written around that.
Another piece of baggage that 10BASE-T had to carry was the MAC sub-layer constraints of older Ethernet standards. (Ethernet frame format, minimum and maximum frame lengths, Inter-Frame Gap, etc)
The actual timing constraints of 10BASE-T (for CSMA/CD to function) came from older standards.
After the Working Group had concluded on a maximum distance, all they then had to do was define the cabling's minimum characteristics.
To find the minimum length, as defined by the standard, I believe you must study the IEEE 802.1 standard itself. I have seen references to a 2.5m minimum distance between 10BASE-T nodes, but I am not sure if this restriction is written in the standard. I know for a fact that with newer standards' implementations I have used 0.5m patch cords without any issues, but only on Ethernet point-to-point links.
But I noticed a weird phrasing in your question: you are asking about cabling between an end-device and a switch, and whether Collision Detection will work. Unless you are using a hub or a bridge (a very old device type), you should not be even able to produce collisions in this connection.
So, to answer your question "what is the minimum cable length (or minimum segment length) between end device and switch, so as to ensure Collision Detection works during Half Duplex operation", the answer is:
It's an impossible question to answer. You cannot get a Collision on a device connected to a switch with a UTP cable. You need something else that creates a shared medium somewhere. So, no, there is no minimum length of cable that will allow collision detection to work on an end-device or a switch directly connected to each other with a UTP cable.

A collision is possible any time half-duplex is in use. Neither side can know when the other is going to transmit, so they can step on each other. Try it for yourself - ptp link two computers forced to half-duplex, then do anything more intense than "ping." "The Serial Port" on youtube recently had a video using some very ancient cabletron hubs if you just want to watch someone else do it.

If you're not sure about the standard just read up: https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/browse/standards/get-program/page/series?id=68. Even a switched port goes to half duplex with CSMA/CD if the link partner doesn't support FDX (usually 10/100M only).

A collision is not possible when you connect a switch with a NIC with a UTP. You can have counters go all the way up to infinity, no usable throughput, yet no collisions. Collisions require a shared medium and with twisted cables each Transmitter gets their own wire pair. No collisions possible. Just because a switched port is in half duplex and uses CSMA/CD logic, this does not mean that collisions are possible. To get collisions you need either a hub (which is what the youtube video did, i guess), or a coaxial cable with more than one transmitters.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carrier-sense_multiple_access_with_collision_detection#Local_collision

Local collisions are the only way to detect a collision on twisted pair cabling. Connecting a switched port to a NIC can cause simultaneous transmissions on both cable pairs. In half-duplex mode, the NIC/port will interpret these simultaneous transmissions as a local collision, even if no actual collision occurred. With a hub, this would have been a real collision. However, with a single node and a switched port, local collisions are phantom collisions caused by misconfigured duplex settings.

So if duplex settings match (at half duplex) what stops the switch and the node trying to start transmission at exactly the same time? Just like if 2 people try and talk at the same time accidentally?

If a half duplex transmitter detects a signal on the Rx pair of the UTP, after it has already started a transmitting on the Tx pair, the NIC will incorrectly assume that a collision has occurred. It will then, as per the Ethernet CSMA/CD algorithm, treat the received signal as a local collision. But in reality the signal the NIC transmitted never left the Tx pair, and the received signal that the opposite side sent on the Rx pair, never affected each other, really.

Yes, ok, I agree with this now. At a physical level no electrical signal collisions occur, because the medium isn't "shared" (separate pairs as opposed to a single transmission medium such as coax). However, at algorithm level, according to the CSMA/CD algorithm, a (pseudo) "collision" has occurred and the backoff / retry protocol would kick in.

The 100 m limit for twisted pair - up to 90 m of stiff, solid-core plenum cable, up 10 m of flexible, stranded patch cable - is determined by the electrical performance (mainly attenuation, crosstalk).
The 5-4-3 rule tells us that a half-duplex collision domain may be longer than just two 10BASE-T links - up to five 10BASE-T links may be cascaded over up to four repeaters. You can do the math with known minimum frame size, velocity factors, repeater delays and detection delays (for 10BASE5/2) - see IEEE 802.3 13.4 for details.
Half-duplex Ethernet with CSMA/CD is long obsolete, of course. In theory you could exceed the 100 m with a better cable grade but there is no standard that tells you how far you could go, and you'd be on your own.

is there a stated minimum cable length?

There is no such thing for 10BASE-T. IEEE 802.3 Clause 14.1.1 specifically states operating over 0 m to at least 100 m of twisted pair without the use of a repeater.
There are minimum constraints for some other Ethernet variants, most notably 10BASE5, to ensure reliable collision detection on the shared wire, but there aren't any minimum lengths for TP (or fiber variants for up to 20 km).
